# Does an interferometer add or multiply together signals? Is it either?

Tags: astronomy, interference, interferometry

I'm studying honours physics right now and have to get an understanding of interferometers, specifically in the context of astronomy and interferometer telescope arrays. However, I'm having some trouble as we only covered the basics of interferometers in undergrad. 
We went over stuff like the Michelson-Morley experiment and obviously did wave interference, but not as much in terms of modern application.

It seems to me that devices where multiple light beams are sent to interfere directly, and then detected, are called interferometers. This makes sense to me as you are using the interference of the two signals to measure something or to filter noise.

But, in the notes I have for my project, the basic example of an interferometer array made of two telescope dishes looking at some source has the signal correlation be a multiplication instead. I understand that this would also show you where the signals correlate, and would cancel out some random noise that is specific to one of the telescopes. But this doesn't really seem like it is interference.
Or am I just doing wrong something really basic to do with interference?
Thanks.

Comment: Please can you refer to a published example where signals are multiplied together and also what type of interferometer it is. There is a difference between intensity interferometers and phase interferometers.

Comment: Multiplication would be a non linear operation.

Comment: The the interferometer that we are going to simulate is a radio telescope array. After looking into it for a bit, it looks like that infrared/photon counting observation uses normal Michelson-like interfrometry, where they combine the light in front of a CCD. However, it seems that in radio interferometry they instead correlate the signals by multiplying them, and then the combined signal varies over time as you measure it due to earth's rotation. Anyone can tell me why they do it this way instead?